# Swift 3 : prepare segue get view control atleast three scene

Tags: swift3

I need to get the 5th scene after i click the login using 
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

solved.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let next : UITabBarController = segue.destination as! UITabBarController

        let next1 : TopTabBarController = next.viewControllers![0] as! TopTabBarController

        let next2 : UINavigationController = next1.viewControllers![0] as! UINavigationController

        let next3 : VehicleTableViewController = next2.topViewController as! VehicleTableViewController

        next3.userid = "abcdefghijklmn";
    }
```